# How to benchmark performance before jumping into match

Tags: overwatch

I'd like to make the game look as good as possible, but also dont want to drop to 10FPS in the middle on a match.

Any way to tryout a high CPU consuming scenario before jumping into a game? (So I can try to maximize performance but keep it over 30 FPS)

Comment: Unless your CPU is very old (like Core2Duo-old or older) or very low end, chances are Overwatch's performance is bottlenecked by your GPU instead. Besides, is there a reason why you think the Training mode isn't good enough as benchmark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no video benchmark in overwatch to test your hardware capabilities.

But you can either play a regular game vs. AI. This would fill up your team with random players.

Or you can create a custom game and fill both teams with AI.

You can't really simulate the most demanding situations but you get an idea about where you are in terms of frame drops. In case of the 30 FPS as your lower limit, better make sure you don't drop below 35 FPS while testing.

Comment: Good answer.  The training mode itself is too clean of debris and multiple targets using flashy ults. A solo bot match would provide better results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was my plan B, but it seems the plan A doesn't exist. My Plan A was something like in the Tomb Raider Reboot that would try to render things that are hard for computers to run to be able to see the dip in the FPS. But seems that this doesn't exist.